# How to read/understand parameters list in Php docs

Tags: php, documentation

Looking through the php docs, i find the syntax of parameters confusing. For example, for the simple array_push, the docs stated

```
int array_push ( array &$array [, mixed $... ] )
```

Can someone explain how it should be readed?

Comment: `int` means it returns an integer, `&$array` means it's done by reference, `[]` brackets mean optional, `array` and `mixed` are what data types

Comment: To build on that, `...` means you can pass multiple arguments here and push them all onto `$array`

Comment: Done by reference means you need to pass something that can be written to (e.g. a variable, but not the result of a function/method call).

Comment: Thank you, now i understand all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array_push push the value in the array end.

```
$abc = ['a', 'b'];

array_push($abc, 'c', 'd');

print_r($abc);
```